# Is there a way (not date) to number photos sequentially.

Tags: stock-android, photos

My regular digital camera assigns numbers sequentially.  My Android 8.0 Galaxy S8+, after the date, assigns random numbers to each picture. If copied to a computer the pics all become "created" at the same time. I'd like them numbered in the sequence taken. Samsung says it's a logarithm naming matter and what I want "can't be done". I don't believe that. It's a computer. Why wouldn't it be able to do it?

Comment: Is it a random number or the time? Ex: 20181102_154430 Being Nov 2, 2018 @ 3:44:30 PM

Comment: "If copied to a computer the pics all become "created" at the same time." That means you use MTP to copy them, right? It's MTP that causes the date being set to "now". To correcting that, and naming them sequentially, there is e.g. `exiftool` you could use on the PC. The correct date is still held in Exif data inside the image files, which is what `exiftool` uses to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, all digital cameras follow the Design rule for Camera File system ([DCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system)), a Japan Electronics and Information Technology Industries Association [JEITA](https://www.jeita.or.jp/english/) standard ([CP-3461B](https://www.jeita.or.jp/cgi-bin/standard_e/list.cgi?cateid=1&subcateid=4)) for digital cameras. This is why your digital camera sequences the photos.

Phones do not necessarily have to follow this standard, since they are not just digital cameras. Phone storage still used the DCIM folder to give a standardized placement for photos, but this does not mean that they photo file names will follow the standard.

As far as phones storing photo with sequential numbers, yes, it is possible that they could do that. It would mean changing how the file names are generated to use a sequencing number instead of the randomly generated number or, in my case with the S9, the use of the time in military format for the second half.